# memory-mapped files in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, memory-mapped-files

I'm currently using Neo4j for my research and I'm trying to get a better understanding of it.
I'd like to know more on how the memory-mapped files mechanism works. 
I tried to play a bit with the parameters of neo4j to see how different settings for the memory-mapped files affect the performance, but I did not get much out of it.

Unfortunately, the documentation that I find on the Neo4j website does not give many details.

Do you happen to know a good reference (article or book) that gives some technical details on the memory-mapped files mechanism of Neo4j and, in general, on the parameters that are important for its performances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also check http://neo4j.org/develop/internals for some helpful links.

Answer (score 1):

There is an almost 4-year-old [blog entry](http://digitalstain.blogspot.com/2010/10/neo4j-internals-persistence-and-memory.html) that goes into neo4j memory mapping.